# Summing products of multiple row cells in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I did not quite know how to call this problem in the title. This is from my assignment in school I can't seem to solve with my current knowledge.
I have the following table:
[image: SQL table]

My problem asks me the following: `Determine the order total for each order that has an order total greater than 100. Display ‘Order Id’ and ‘Order Total’. Make sure the results are in ascending order total sequence.`

Here is my query:

```
SELECT order_id, SUM(qty*order_price) as Order_Total 
FROM alp_orderline
GROUP BY order_id
HAVING Order_Total > 100 
ORDER BY Order_Total ASC
```

But, it only looks at the first occurrence of `order_id`. I want it to take all rows with the same id, then look at different `inv_id`'s there, multiply `qty` by `order_price` and sum them.

Here's what my query gives me:
[image]

Comment: Good news for you: Your current query already looks correct to me.  What about it makes you think it is not correct?

Comment: Your query is just fine. You have mostly `qty=1` everywhere, that is probably why you are confused. what is wrong from your point of view? what another result do you expect?

Comment: Hell, you are correct. 274.90 and 274.99  kept me confused all along. Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to look at different inv_id's there you just need to add one more group by, like this:

```
SELECT    
    inv_id,
    order_id,
    SUM(qty*order_price) as Order_Total
FROM alp_orderline
GROUP BY
    inv_id,
    order_id
    HAVING 
        Order_Total > 100
    ORDER BY 
        Order_Total ASC;
```

You could also use sub-query and then in the outer query you would have a condition where 
Order_Total > 100